# 日本語に違和感: プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心"の"人向け

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

画面左上にあるプルダウンメニュー(画像1枚目)から辿ることのできる、スタック・オーバーフローの対象者の説明文(画像2枚目)に少し違和感を覚えました。

次のように、熱心の人向けではなく、熱心な人向けがより適切かと思っています。

修正前：プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人向け

修正後：プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心**な**人向け

1枚目：プルダウンメニュー
[image: プルダウンメニュー]

2枚目：対象者の記述
[image: スタック・オーバーフローの説明文のキャプチャ]

Comment: 投稿先はここであってます。http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1429/8000 での修正漏れですかね…。

Comment: ありがとうございます。リンク先を拝見しました。
リンク先を見て気付きましたが、私が投稿したものはスタック・オーバーフロー(ja.stackoverflow.com)で見たものですが、どうやらStackOverflow(stackoverflow.com)においても、"For プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人"となっているようですね。
(=日本語版では"熱心の人"問題が残っている、英語版では"熱心の人"問題+"For"の記載が残っている)

Comment: 「For」は今見ているサイトの言語に合わせているんでしょうね。例えばスクリーンショットに写っているロシア語版StackOverflowの説明にも「向け」が付いてます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

少し時間がかかりましたが、適切な日本語に修正されましたのでお知らせいたします m(_ _)m

[image]