# 日本語に違和感: 新規ユーザーのサイドバーに表示されるようこそメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[既に何度か言及されている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E7%86%B1%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA%20is%3Aq)「プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人」を見逃すとしても、ところどころ文章が不自然です。Transifexにも登録されていないようです。

> ようこそ！
>
> このサイトは**プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人**向けの質問と回答サイトです。完全に無料し、アカウント登録は不要です。
>
> このサイトに関しての質問はありますか？ [meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にどの質問を聞いたらいい、どのタグを使えばいい等を質問できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4):

2022/12/07に反映を確認いたしました‍♀️
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

改善案です。どうぞ直接ご編集くださいませ。
コミュニティからプラス票がいくつか集まりましたら反映させて行きたいと思います。

---

**現在の文章**　( [mjy さんのスクリーンショットより](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3779/14055))

> ようこそ！
>
> このサイトは**プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人**向けの質問と回答サイトです。完全に無料し、アカウント登録は不要です。
>
> このサイトに関しての質問はありますか？ [meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にどの質問を聞いたらいい、どのタグを使えばいい等を質問できます。

**改善案**

> ようこそ！
>
> スタック・オーバーフローは**プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人**向けの Q&A サイトです。
>
> [メインサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)での質問の仕方や適切なタグの使い方などサイト自体に関する質問は [Meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) で受け付けています。

- 日本語の表現が不自然な箇所を編集しました。
- アカウント登録が2022年9月から必要になりましたので、アカウント登録不要の箇所を削除しました。
- 「無料」という言葉は特に必要ないのではないかと思い、削除しました。

なお、以下の修正は[2018年7月](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2411/14055)に完了済みでした。
プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心**の**人　→ プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心**な**人

Comment: 更新されたメッセージが正しく表示されているかどうかを何度も確認してくれてありがとうございます！ :)